# Is possible to deploy angular app in weblogic 12c?

Tags: angular, deployment, weblogic, war, web-deployment

I developed a project with a frontend in angular and backend that it´s a spring boot application.

Two parts are independent.

The backend was deployed in weblogic 12c and it works perfectly.

Now, I need to deploy de native angular in weblogic too. I dont´t any information to do that.

Is it possible to deploy angular app in weblogic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can deploy in weblogic 12c, Please *implements* the *WebApplicationInitializer*
in spring boot application.
Put your angular build in webapp folder.
Create build and it will work.